# Holes in rational functions

Tags: limits, graphing-functions, rational-functions

I'm learning about holes in rational functions in precalculus, and  I'm confused as to why they exist, having some knowledge of limits. Say I have a function $R(x)=\frac{(x-5)(x+2)}{(x+4)(x+2)}$. If I were to find where the hole lies for this function, I would plug $-2$ into $\frac{x-5}{x+4}$ which would give me a hole at $(-2, -\frac{7}{2})$. However, that turns out to be the limit of $R(x)$ (using L'Hopital's Rule):

$$\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{(x-5)(x+2)}{(x+4)(x+2)}=\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x^2-3x-10}{x^2+6x+8}=\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{2x-3}{2x+6}=-\frac{7}{2}$$

So why is there a hole in the graph if the limit exists at $(-2, -\frac{7}{2})$? Am I misunderstanding the definition of a limit? Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html) could be helpful,hole means that $-2$ is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: because if you plug $-2$ into the original function, you get $\frac{0}{0}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of definition of the function $R$ is the set of all reals $x$ such that $(x+4)(x+2)$ is not equal to $0$, to avoid division by $0$ when evaluating. This is the definition or a convention if you prefer. (One could do things differently, too, but this is what was agreed upon.)

It is true that the limit you mention exists. Therefore you could define a new function $Q(x)$ that agrees with $R(x)$ everywhere where $R$ is defined and in addition $Q(-2)= -7/2$, and this function would be a *continuous* function.

Thus *this type* of "hole" can be plugged, and one thus calls it a removable "hole" (or a removable singularity). By contrast, the "hole" at $-4$ cannot be plugged in this way.

Comment: When one has two functions $f,g$ defined on the reals, then one considers *at least initially* the function $f/g$ to be defined only for those reals where $g(x)\neq 0$. Mostly, since initially one does not want to bother with checking where limits exist, also as the definition should also make sense to somebody not knowing limits. As a second step one can then do the considerations you undertook, and extend the domain of definition. One could do things differently too, but the convention is like it is; see https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10317/ for some more thoughts around this.